# how do I implement a start timer in a digital circuit

Tags: vhdl, timer, counter

In vhdl, I know how to code a start timer behavorially. However, if I have to implement such a counter to start based on a trigger, how could I implement such a counter?

My trigger is another signal that will be active for only one clock cycle.
I'm breaking my head trying to think of how this is done. I could add logic to check if my trigger is active high (1 and-ed to my signal) but then it will go inactive after 1 clock cycle.

I've seen counters with enable but I want to count and stay counting no matter what.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Do you want to have a hardware circuit or software solution ? Can you rephrase "I could add logic to check if my trigger is active high (1 and-ed to my signal) but then it will go inactive after 1 clock cycle."?

Comment: @Damien Umm hardware but not HDL behavioral. I want to actually understand the circuit. But now that I think about it even more, Im realizing I'm not experimenting with Dff or other sequential logic modules enough.

Comment: my trigger signal is from a circuit that checks if an event happens. but the event only happens once every so often. I want my counter to start only when the signal is active high. however, when it is active high, it will only be in that state for one clock cycle. so if I use that signal for my enable in my counter, my counter will stop after the first cycle is done. I also want to restart the counter again, once the trigger signal is active high again (which should be long after the counter ends).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can ensure that the trigger signal is high for at least one full clock cycle, you can do something as simple as this:

[image: trigger]

*circuit built with www.falstad.com*

The trigger doesn't need to be synchronous with the clock, but it does need to be held high for at least a full clock cycle. Otherwise, the trigger may not be registered by the flip-flop (DFF).

You can also add a reset to the DFF if desired, to disable the `enable` and allow the circuit to be retrigger.

If you're concerned about metastability, just add a second DFF stage.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're still talking about VHDL, to add a start signal just create a two state counter. One `idle` state where you're waiting for the enable signal to be active and then transit to the regular `counter` state.